# C++ Crash (Compiler?)

Tags: c++, crash

I have a very simple program I'm starting up, but when I try to run it, it gets to "has an initial population of" then crashes every time. For context, I am using visual studio 2015 on windows 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/*Ideas for features to add
*----------------------------
*Trade, agriculture, traffic, tourism, housing, crime rate, language, religion
*/

string version = "1.0";
void main() {
    cout << "Welcome to Population Simulator v" + version + ".\n";
    cout << "In this game we will simulate a city and how the population numbers change over time.\n";
    //City initialization 
    cout << "Please input a name for your city: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Please input an initial population of the city (Recommended: 10,000): ";
    int population = 0;
    cin >> population;
    int initialPopulation = population;
    int initialWealth = population * 10000;
    int wealth = initialWealth;
    int year = 2000;
    cout << name + " has an initial population of ";
    cout << population + " and an initial net-worth of $" + wealth;
    cout << ".\n";


}
int weather() {
    return 0;
}
int NPG() { //natural population growth
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't add string literals to integers (or rather you *can*, but it won't do what you think it does), use `name << " has an initial population of ";` etc. instead.

Comment: Continue reading your C++ book until you get to the part that teaches you how to `cout` things!

Comment: I'm not sure why people are hating on this question. It seems to be a very reasonable question for someone learning C++. Given that the compiler doesn't complain about the problem expression, it's entirely non-obvious what the problem is.  Even stepping through in a debugger is unlikely to help a newbie since you'd probably have to step into the C++ library header templates (yikes!) or into the assembly language (which would probably be easier to understand) to notice what the problem is. This is a much better novice question than 99% of what gets posted on SO today.

Answer (score 4):

The expression:

```
population + " and an initial net-worth of $" + wealth
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  It's performing arithmetic on the char pointer that points to `" and an initial net-worth of $"` resulting in an invalid pointer that causes the crash when the program tries to print using it.

Try:

```
cout << population << " and an initial net-worth of $" << wealth;
```

Comment: Thanks! This was it. I just recently came back to C++ after a couple other languages, so I forgot how it went.